# The Monodroid-equivalent to searchable in Android

Tags: c#, android-manifest, xamarin.android

i'm searching the equivalent to Androids [searchable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) in Monodroid, because monodroid generates the application xml manifest automatically. Is there a way to have an own application xml and say to the monodroid compiler that this xml should be bound into compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding those lines to the Search-Activity it generates the correct manifest:

```
[IntentFilter (new[]{Intent.ActionSearch})]
[MetaData ("android.app.searchable", Resource="@xml/searchable")]
```

This is all.

For further information look at http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml